# XML Error - Extra content at end of document?

Tags: php, xml

My XML is looking perfect but not working. I get a error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Other answers from other posts aren't helping

```
<?php
$csv = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, "|");},file('quotes.csv'));
$hdrs = array_shift($csv);
    
$count = 0;

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$xml .= '<quotes>';

foreach($csv as $k=>$v) {
    $xml .= '<record id="' . ++$count .'">';
    foreach($hdrs as $h=>$i) {
        $xml .= '<' . $i . '>' . htmlspecialchars($v[$h], ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8') . '</' . $i . '>';
    }
    $xml .= '</record>';
}

$xml .= '</quotes>';

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $xml;
?>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<quotes>
<record id="1">
<quote>There is no remedy but to love more.</quote>
<source>Henry David Thoreau</source>
<dob-dod>1817-1862</dob-dod>
<wplink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau</wplink>
<wpimg>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Benjamin_D._Maxham_-_Henry_David_Thoreau_-_Restored.jpg</wpimg>
<category>love</category>
</record>
</quotes>
```

Comment: Do not try and build your XML document by adding strings together, it's a common reason for problems.

Comment: May fix this with removing `?>` at the end of the php file. When there is any space after the `?>` this will be extra content in the xml. `?>` is never needed at the end of a php file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XMLWriter, its quite easy and it will generate valid XML. Doing your own manually is always likely to cause little anomalies.

```
$lines = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, "|");},file('quotes.csv'));
$hdrs = array_shift($lines);

$count = 0;

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openUri('php://stdout');

$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('quotes');

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $xml->startElement("record");
    $xml->writeAttribute('id', ++$count);
    foreach($hdrs as $i=>$name) {
        $xml->writeElement($name, htmlspecialchars($line[$i], ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8') );
    }
    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
$xml->flush();
```

> The [XMLWriter Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) in the manual

Using this data

```
source|dob-dod|wplink|wpimg|category
Henry David Thoreau|1817-1862|http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau|http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Benjamin_D._Maxham_-_Henry_David_Thoreau_-_Restored.jpg|love
Sir Benjamin Baker|1840-1907|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Baker_(engineer)|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Baker_(engineer)#/media/File:BBaker.jpg|Engineers
```

We get this result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<quotes>
 <record id="1">
  <source>Henry David Thoreau</source>
  <dob-dod>1817-1862</dob-dod>
  <wplink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau</wplink>
  <wpimg>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Benjamin_D._Maxham_-_Henry_David_Thoreau_-_Restored.jpg</wpimg>
  <category>love</category>
 </record>
 <record id="2">
  <source>Sir Benjamin Baker</source>
  <dob-dod>1840-1907</dob-dod>
  <wplink>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Baker_(engineer)</wplink>
  <wpimg>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Baker_(engineer)#/media/File:BBaker.jpg</wpimg>
  <category>Engineers</category>
 </record>
</quotes>
```

Comment: im getting a value error on this line ->>>        $xml->writeElement($i, htmlspecialchars($v[$h], ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8'));  Argument #2 ($content) must be a valid element name?